# Play Animation Node not working

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have default player character, and which is affected by his health. On attaining zero health, he will die. I want to run animation on '0' health

So i prepared a node function 'playerdeath' which i am able to call successfully, but the animation selected in the node is not working. Can you help me where i am doing wrong ??

Thanks[image]

Comment: Is your character's animation ordinarily controlled by an animation blueprint? If so, you'll want to define slot playback nodes in your animation blueprint, and use animation montages to play animations on them, as described here: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Introduction_to_Third_Person_Blueprint_Game_-_20_-_Using_Slot_Nodes_and_Branch_Points_in_UE4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this to run your mesh's animation class should be set to none